# iOS app view looks different on simulator than the XIB file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying out iOS programming from the Big Nerd Ranch programming book for iOS programming. I have created the BNR classes as mentioned, and my `xib` file looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, everything in the screen is perfectly centered, so I expect it would look the same in the IOS simulator as well. However when I run it, I get it like this:

[image]

Not only do I have to scroll down to see the elements below, the things are not centered at all, with everything pushed to the right (without scroll) so that almost half of the view is not accessible.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Interface Builder, select the view, and click on the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" button: [image], and then select "Add missing constraints" as seen here:

[image]

You can also change the Interface Builder size, as seen here:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I am completely new to iOS development, so no idea where these things are located. Where will the 'Resolve auto-layout issues' button show up? And 'Add missing constraints'?

Comment: It's in the bottom right corner of your screen. If you look closely, it's even present on your screenshot. This is also documented in the BNR guide.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. And how do I do the second part, that is changing the size of IB to iPhone 5s? The blue icon in the inspector panel is the attribute selector, I don't see any such option there..

Comment: If you have your view selected, the "size" option should be available. Make sure you don't have any of your UI controls selected.

Comment: Yes it is working correctly now. Thanks. Do I have to verify each step in all devices like this, or once I get comfortable with Auto Layout, things will take care of themselves?

Comment: The latter is to more likely, but as with anything, it's better to verify your application looks correct in all simulator resolutions (or devices, if available).

Comment: By the way, I still have to scroll vertically. After changing the interface type to iPhone 5s, I moved up the bottom views so that they are visible without scrolling. But I still have to scroll in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

U should use autolayout. Add constraints automatically or hold the right button of your mouse in your `UIButton` and slide to the side into your view and release, then select `center horizontally` etc.